# Need help decoding a possible encrypted base64 string from API

Tags: encryption, base64, reverse-engineering

I'm on a task to reverse enineering an API to a controller for an oven.

The command for turning on the oven is:

`api/directmessages?base64encodedMessage=wkMCUAs=`

To turn it off:

`api/directmessages?base64encodedMessage=wkMCUAo=`

Problem is that I'm not able to decode the base64-string provided in the parameter in any decoder. And i'm kind of stuck.

Anyone seen a string like this that can help me out?

Comment: Looks like normal, correctly padded, Base64 strings, each containing 5 bytes. Decoded to Hex: c2 43 02 50 0a and 
c2 43 02 50 0b.

Comment: yes, but that translates to nothing really. If i translate the hex to text i get  :  � C  P . Should it not be more human-readable?

Comment: I have really not much context, but usually, I would expect that the human user clicks on a button in some kind of UI and doesn't have to type the commands anywhere. And for the API it's certainly easier to have a clear binary message (probably some kind of protocol with some meta info)  than to parse human-readable text.

Comment: @kirkegaard *Should it not be more human-readable?* Why should it? The first four bytes `c2 43 02 50` look like an enum stand for the turn on/off command, and the last byte `0a`/`0b` is the state. It makes perfect sense to me.